# Что именно вызывает программный интерфейс stdlib.h?

Tags: c, lib

Когда я в С пишу так:

```
#define <stlib.h>
```

А ниже вот так:

```
void *ptr=malloc(1);
```

То должна вызываться библиотечная ф-ия malloc, верно? А где её реализация? Я что-то никак не могу найти.
Это будет вызов из .so или как? Можете рассказать как это устроено?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Статическая компоновка

Если разбираться, задача вызова чужих функций по имени решается непросто. Именно для её решения введён промежуточный уровень между исходным кодом и исполняемым кодом, а именно *объектные код*. Программа проходит (упрощённо) две стадии компиляции — создание объектных модулей и *компоновку* (она же *линковка*).

В объектом модуле хранится машинный код, но, кроме этого, и имена вместе с адресами объектов: процедур и структур данных.

Форматы объектных модулей могут быть разными. Для DOS формат был разработан фирмой Intel в незапамятные времена, ещё для архитектуры x86. Его более-менее придерживались разработчики разных языков и сред, так что теоретически можно было компоновать библиотеки, созданные разными компиляторами и даже из разных языков.

Характерным исключением являлся Turbo Pascal и Borland Delphi, там использовался свой собственный объектный формат — `*.dcu`.

В UNIX и Windows использовался стандарт COFF, не привязанный к архитектуре. Сейчас в UNIX-мире закрепился ELF. Для небольших микропроцессорных систем применяется IEEE695.

Кроме форматов, есть ещё набор условий, по которым модули могут быть совместимы друг с другом. Они включают, например, соглашения о передаче параметров, битность архитектуры, модель памяти и т.д.

Теперь о том, как это работает. Каждая функция в каждом исходном модуле должна быть реализована в этом модуле. Если это не так, компилятор ожидает, что функция будет описана: какие параметры она принимает, и что возвращает. Эта информация позволяет компилятору сгенерировать код для вызова функции с этими параметрами «пока неизвестно откуда».

При генерации кода компилятор сохраняет в объектом модуле все места вызова внешней функции. Когда её адрес станет известен, его нужно будет обновить во всех этих местах.

Все внутренние функции (которые реализованы в модуле), компилятор вызывает по известному адресу, но этот адрес относительный, то есть отсчитывается от начала модуля.

Все функции и данные, не помеченные ключевым словом `static` видимы из других модулей, то есть в объектом модуле хранится таблица соответствия имён и относительных адресов. Вы можете не только вызывать функции из других модулей, но обращаться к массивами и переменным из этих модулей.

Далее, если вы создаете библиотеку функций, например, *стандартную библиотеку*, то удобно все эти сотни объектных модулей слить в один файл, такой файл называется *библиотечным*. Важно, что при компоновке программы из библиотечного файла будут доставаться только нужные объектные модули, а не все.

Теперь, внимание, фокус: при компиляции программы вы явно указываете, из чего она должна состоять. Вы перечисляете все `*.c` файлы, все `*.o` или `*.obj` файлы, а также все `*.lib` или `*.a` файлы. Компилятор создает объектные модули из исходного кода, а потом передает их все, включая те, которые вы явно указали, компоновщику.

Компоновщик собирает исполняемый модуль. Он добавляет все объектные модули друг за другом, и пересчитывает адреса так, чтобы они отсчитывались уже от начала исполняемого образа. Объектный модуль — это наименьшая единица компоновки: нельзя взять из него только одну функцию, или один массив, только всё вместе. А вот из библиотек выбираются только нужные объектные модули.

Компоновщик также *разрешает ссылки*, то есть сопоставляет имена и прописывает адреса. На этом этапе уже не существует никаких типов, поэтому компоновщик не может проверить соответствие параметров, или ещё что-нибудь в этом роде. Он просто сверяет имена.

В результате у вас получается исполняемый файл, который и будет загружен загрузчиком при старте программы. Загрузчик в свою очередь может изменить некоторые относительные адреса на абсолютные, это зависит от операционной системы, архитектуры, и так далее, то есть нужно такое далеко не всегда. Я пишу это затем, что эта часть становится важна при динамическом связывании кода.

> **Краткое отступление.** Если объектные модули, производимые разными компиляторами, совместимы друг с другом, то можно компоновать даже модули, написанные на разных языках. Довольно часто встречается случай C и C++, но он простой. Однако, вы можете сочетать Fortran и C, или Pascal и C. Обычно в этом случае вам приходится явно следить за соглашениями о вызовах и использовать странные ключевые слова наподобие `_cdecl`, `_stdcall` и т.д.

Если вы вызываете одну функцию на C из другой функции на C, которые находятся в разных исходных файлах, то по умолчанию соглашения у них совпадают, и вам не надо об этом заботиться.

#### Динамическая компоновка

У процедуры, описанной выше, есть один большой недостаток: все нужные объектные модули будут зашиты в исполняемый модуль. Стандартная библиотека используется во всех программах, значит, она лежит на диске в десятках и сотнях экземпляров.

В идеале, она должна быть в одном экземпляре, и программы должны подгружать объектные модули из одного стандартного места.

Эти динамически подключаемые библиотеки широко распространены во всех современных операционных системах. В Windows это `*.dll`, а в Linux — `*.so`.

По сути это те же самые библиотечные файлы, которые, правда, подгружаются  целиком. Окончательную привязку адресов выполняет уже не компоновщик, а загрузчик. Алгоритм приблизительно такой же: в самом простом случае при старте приложения сразу подгружаются все динамические библиотеки, которые ему нужны, и загрузчик прописывает реальные адреса функций во все места вызовов.

Естественно, в таком библиотечном файле явно прописаны имена всех экспортируемых методов и данных.

#### Когда и что используется

Может возникнуть мысль, что статическая и динамическая компоновки строго противоречат друг другу, однако это не так. Вы можете часть библиотек подключить статически, а часть динамически. Динамические библиотеки вы даже можете подгружать явно в своей программе, но в этом случае вы не сможете вызывать сами функции непосредственно, а только через указатель на функцию.

Вариантов много, но у вас простой случай.

Когда вы вызываете `malloc`, компилятор из аргументов понимает, что речь идёт о динамической компоновке (на эту мысль меня наводит упоминание `*.so` файлов). Это значит, что ваш исполняемый модуль при загрузке будет требовать наличия определённых динамических библиотек, которые перечислены внутри него вместе с именами функций.

Загрузчик найдёт эти библиотеки, загрузит их в адресное пространство программы, и пропишет корректные адреса во всех местах вызова. При вызове `malloc` будет вызвана функция по прямому адресу, без всякий указателей на функцию — самым быстрым образом.

#### Disclaimer

Вся эта информация представлена в обобщённом виде. Для отдельных форматов, операционных систем, компиляторов могут существовать дополнительные соглашения.

Например:

1. В объектных модулях размещают в том числе отладочную информацию.
2. В объектных модулях размещают частичный результат компиляции. Например, это *необходимо* в C++ для того, чтобы «прятать» исходный код обобщённых (шаблонизированных) классов. Естественно, это всё нестандартно. Когда я с этим разбирался, существовали отдельные, чуть не экспериментальные компиляторы, которые это поддерживали. Не знаю, как обстоят дела на фронте сейчас.
3. В системе компиляторов Top Speed система форматов была сложнее описанной, потому что разработчики хотели максимально использовать одни и те же инструменты для разных языков, например, использовался общий низкоуровневый оптимизатор. Это значит, что общие файлы использовались и до уровня объектных модулей.
4. В DOS/Windows существует формат исполняемых файлов `*.com`. Он не требует коррекции адресов, фактически, его достаточно загрузить в оперативную память, и передать управление на первую инструкцию, и он сразу заработает. Всё это возможно из-за сегментной организации памяти в архитектуре x86, и из-за того, что `*.com` файл должен помещаться в одном сегменте.

Поэтому в некоторых случаях всё может оказаться сложнее или проще, чем здесь описано. Лучше по конкретным вопросам сверяться с документацией.

Comment: Благодарю за столь развернутый ответ. Проясните пожалуйста:
1. _*.lib_ по факту ничем не отличается от *.obj?
2. В исполяемое приложение попадает весь код библиотеки или только вызванные сущности?
3. Когда вы писали про формат объектного файла, вы имели ввиду ABI?

Comment: @MikeAJ 1.*.lib это по сути набор *.obj, отличие в этом. 2. Объектный модуль это наименьшая единица подключения: если вы ссылаетесь на функцию из модуля, вы получите его весь. А из библиотеки вы получите не всю библиотеку, а только нужные объектные модули. Поэтому размер программы можно сократить, помещая в один модуль связанные функции, которые часто вызываются вместе, а несвязанные функции помещая в разные модули. 3. Под стандартами я имел в виду [COFF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF), ELF.

Comment: Теперь стало понятней. Сохранил Ваш ответ, как шпаргалку :)

Comment: Я читал недавно про фронтенды компилятора под LLVM. Получается объектные файлы полученные проходом фронтенда с нескольких разных языков совместимы по формату и могут корректно линковаться между собой. Это тоже самое, как ваш пример с 
 _"Его более-менее придерживались разработчики разных языков   и сред, так что теоретически можно было компоновать  библиотеки, созданные разными компиляторами и даже из разных языков."_  ?

Comment: @MikeAJ Возможно. У меня нет опыта работы с LLVM, аналогия может оказаться ложной, потому что байт-код находится на более высоком уровне, чем машинный, например, он может включать мета-данные.

Answer (score 2):

Примерно-грубо так - теперь компилятор знает, что есть такая функция `malloc`, которая принимает аргумент такого-то типа, возвращает значение такого типа. И может создать код, который подготовит фактические аргументы для вызова, сделает вызов - вот тут он пока впишет просто имя, грубо говоря, а потом, после вызова, он будет знать откуда и как забрать возвращаемое значение и что с ним делать.

Теперь вступает в дело компоновщик (линковщик). Он видит, что есть вызов по имени, ищет это имя в библиотеках (ну, сначала в ваших объектных файлах, но, понятно, что там-то ее нет), находит, и добавляет в выполнимый файл код самой функции из библиотеки, а команду вызова по имени заменяет на вызов по соответствующему адресу. Если это статическая компоновка. Если динамическая - то просто вставляет код вызова функции из динамической библиотеки.

Примерно так.

Т.е. реализация ее - в виде объектного кода - в статически компонуемой библиотеке. Или в виде выполнимого кода - в динамической, а в линкуемой библиотеке соответственно указание на то, где ее искать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А в итоге такой вызов в linux вызовет ф-ию  malloc из динамической или из стат-ой либы? А как компилятор находит имя сущности в исполняемом файле, ведь в бинарном .so уже нет букв (или там в секции кода сохраняются константные строки?)?

Comment: После отличного ответа @Mark, как мне кажется, отвечать уже не надо? :)